# Why are the intuitions offered by "classic" visual depictions of functions from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so reliable at informing a logical argument?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

Chapter 4 of Michael Spivak's *Calculus* is a swift overview of the *classic* visual representation of functions with a domain in $\mathbb R$ and a range in $\mathbb R$. In particular, each ordered pair, denoted as $\{ x, f(x) \}$, that is a member of this function is visually depicted through the use of a *horizontal* axis, which corresponds to the first component of the ordered pair, and a *vertical* axis, which corresponds to the second component of the ordered pair. Importantly, each axis is a straight line, and the axes intersect at $90^{\circ}$ angles. There is/are certainly more structure/regulations regarding the invocation of a **Cartesian Coordinate System** (rules of plotting, etc), but you get the point. The summarized theme of this fourth chapter is effectively:

> Depicting $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ functions in this aforementioned manner will be useful in guiding problem solving for future chapters.

Having completed all of the exercises in the first seven chapters of this book, I certainly agree! Representing $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ functions in this manner consistently produces trustworthy intuition on how to navigate my formal arguments. Well...at least "trustworthy" in the sense that I arrive at an answer the solution manual agrees with!

However, the more I think about it, the less I understand why this is the case (i.e. *why is it the case that these visual representations...and the rules that govern such Cartesian representations...orient my arguments so well*?). Arguably, the manner in which one decides to convert a symbolic/syntactic entity like "$\{ x, f(x) \}$" into a visual object is completely arbitrary.

It seems to me that any of the below visual representations of dual axes, each perhaps with its own unique plotting rule-system, could potentially be valid (where $\color{\orange}{\text{orange}}$ represents the axis of the first component, $\color{\black}{\text{black}}$ represents the axis of the second component, and the $\color{\purple}{\text{purple}}$ tick mark denotes $0$):

[image: pics]

Could these alternative axes (with alternative plotting rules) also offer appropriate correspondences to the formal reasoning needed in Real Analysis? Or is there something particularly unique about the Cartesian Coordinate System that makes it the most well-suited at informing logical arguments needed in Real Analysis?

Comment: Do you mean that observing "facts" on curvilinear representations can as well lead to hypotheses building ?

Comment: @JeanMarie after Googling "curvilinear"...yes! I'd say that would be a good interpretation of the question.

Comment: Given $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, its **graph** is the set $\text{G}(f) := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon y = f(x)\}$.  Thus, a pair $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ satisfies $y = f(x)$ if and only if $(x,y)$ lies on the subset $\text{G}(f) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.  Given a function $f$, knowing when a particular pair $(x,y)$ satisfies $y = f(x)$ is a basic thing to want to know, which explains the importance of the set $\text{G}(f) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.  How you see $\text{G}(f)$ will depend on how you see $\mathbb{R}^2$, and yes, there are plenty of coordinate systems one could use.

Comment: The set $\mathbb{R}^2$ has several natural structures: it is a **manifold** (which means you can introduce coordinate systems $(u,v)$), it is a **vector space** (which means you can view points $(x,y)$ as "arrows" to be added/subtracted and scaled), and has a natural **inner product** (the dot product).  The usual coordinate system on the manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convenient in that it respects the vector space structure as well as the dot product.  Also, thinking of each axis as a "number line" plays nicely with the typical ordering $\leq$, which is crucial for real analysis.

Answer (score 3):

"Could these alternative axes also offer appropriate correspondences ?"

Yes, I see these two cases at least:

**1st case** If you already have a "ruling" of the 2D space (be it linear or curvilinear) by a *double family of curves*, any global transform:

$$T:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R^2}$$

will generate a "curvilinear ruling" on which you can "track" interesting features just like you can do it with a "linear ruling".

A typical case is when $T$ is issued from a complex transform (think to $\mathbb{R^2} \approx \mathbb{C}$), the classical term being "conformal representation", and I refer you to an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3846833) of mine where the complex derivative is explained in this way.

Remark : the initial "ruling" can a polar ruling by radials $\theta$=const. and circles $|z|=r$, sometimes called "radar-type ruling".

---

**2nd case:** I would like also to attract your attention on a special category of diagrams using curvilinear coordinates, called **nomograms** ; they are usually conceived for 3 connected variables, say $x,y,z$, for example Pression, Volume and Temperature for gases. This kind of tool based on alignments is able

- to provide a numerical evaluation of one of the parameters as a fonction of the 2 others in any order $z$ as a function of $x,y$, but as well $x$ as a function of $y,z$, etc.
- to convey an understanding of "situations", in the broad sense of this term, with a categorization for example in terms of diagnosis.

A certain number of examples, in the domain of health, can be found in this dowloadable [document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234169993_THERMAL_COMFORT/figures?lo=1).

I can find other interesting nomograms in different applied domains if you are interested.